# MKMapkit constraint error when reopen project

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

I built a custom view controller. It has 1 tableview, 2 views and 1 map. When I set the constraints for this layout it works fine. I close project and reopen the map view out of the view controller. The width and height are 1000 points. If I set the map on top of this stack, there is no problem. But when I set map in the middle of the other views, a problem happens. I must put this mapview inside another view or it affects the others, but the problem is still there.

I use Xcode 8 beta 5, and constraint is 0 0 0 0

[image]

Comment: What is "constraint is 0 0 0 0"?

Comment: constraint top, right, bottom and left

Comment: sorry if I ask, but why using a beta version of Xcode? maybe the issue is related to this... does it happens on last Xcode 7?

Comment: I am build prototype app for ios 10 course, so I cant use Xcode 7 :D

Comment: i think you enabled size classes but designing in a fixed size of IB. try to change it once.

Comment: Try to add `centerX`, `centerY` and `equals superview Height`, `equals superview Width` to your mapView (you may need to embed it in another `UIView`).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue in the latest beta. I believe the problem is in the wrong default size, that is always set to 1000x1000 by Xcode for MKMapView.

I would wait for the fix in the next Xcode version.

If you, by some reason, really need it fixed now, you can setup a UIView with constraints as required, then put **MKMapView** inside the **UIView** and use Autoresizing to scale it.

[image]